# How to return a date field to add two days and not affect the original date?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a column that holds a date (MM/DD/YYYY) that someone's account was last updated by an automated service. When this date is two days old we have another automated service that automatically sets a hold on an account.

Basically I need to return the date that the hold was actually placed on the account. The following is my code to return all users who have this placed. e.lastupdate is the field that needs two days added to it

```
select p.id||'    '||p.lastname||'    '||p.firstname||'    '|| e.lastupdate 
from table p, othertable e

where p.id = e.id 
and hold = 8 
and id in (
select id from othertable 
where buildinginfo is null
) 
order by id;
```

Expected results to be two days after the "e.lastupdate" field

Comment: This is going to be really hard for us to help you with without example data, and an actual reproducible example. Please see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: It seems that all you need is a WHERE clause; perhaps something like `where e.lastupdate < sysdate - 2`. This will give you all the rows where the `lastupdate` is more than two days before the current date AND TIME. With that said: what does "two days old" mean in your business? If you must compare to midnight at the beginning of "today", use `trunc(sysdate)` instead of `sysdate`. And decide if you need STRICTLY more than two days or "more than or EQUAL TO two days old" (in which case, use <= instead of <).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the answer you are seeking is simply a question regarding how to work with dates?  If so see my answer which shows how to perform calculations on dates/times.

**The below simply has a new column added to your query called lastupdate_plus_2_days**

```
SELECT p.id||'    '||p.lastname||'    '||p.firstname||'    '|| e.lastupdate + 2
  , e.lastupdate + 2 AS lastupdate_plus_2_days
FROM some_TABLE p, othertable e
WHERE p.id = e.id
AND hold   = 8
AND id    IN
  (
    SELECT id
    FROM othertable
    WHERE buildinginfo IS NULL
  )
ORDER BY id;
```

**Examples Working with Dates**

```
/* Working with SYSDATE and to_char formats */
SELECT
  sysdate -365 Last_Year,
  to_char(to_date('04-DEC-2013', 'DD-MON-YY') - 365, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS Last_Year2,
  add_months(sysdate, -1) Last_Month,
  sysdate -7 Last_Week,
  sysdate -1 Yesterday,
  sysdate Today,
  to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') NOW,
  to_char(sysdate + 1/(24*60*60), 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') "OneSecFrom_NOW",
  to_char(sysdate + 2/(24*60*60), 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') "TwoSecFrom_NOW",
  to_char(sysdate + 1/(24*60), 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') "OneMinFrom_NOW",
  to_char(sysdate + 7/(24*60), 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') "SevMinFrom_NOW",
  to_char(sysdate + 1/24, 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS') "OneHrFrom_NOW",
  sysdate +1 Tomorrow,
  sysdate +7 Next_Week,
  last_day(sysdate) as last_day_of_month,
  add_months(sysdate, 1) Next_Month,
  last_day(add_months(sysdate, 1)) as last_day_of_next_month,
  sysdate +365 Next_Year,
  /* Below are examples of how you could disect a number of days and spit out how many years, months, days are within those days using the mod function. */
  trunc((to_date('02-FEB-14') - to_date('01-JAN-13'))/365) "~yr", trunc(mod((to_date('02-FEB-14') - to_date('01-JAN-13')),365)/31) "~mon", mod(mod((to_date('02-FEB-14') - to_date('01-JAN-13')),365),31) "~days"
FROM
  dual;
```

Is this answer at all what you were looking for?  Unless there is code somewhere performing an 'UPDATE' the original date coming back from your 'SELECT' query will never change the original date value in the table from which you are pulling the data.

Comment: I think this pretty much answers it. I couldn't figure out how to have the date be two days ahead of the date in the field. So what you're basically saying is that without an Update statement it won't return the date I actually need?

Comment: I suppose that depends on how you are planning to retrieve the date?  You can just add to your date +2 to get the date to return but first adding two days to the date... this is just SELECTing so no updates are being made to your Database.

Comment: If you plan to UPDATE a date within your database this would require an UPDATE statement.  For example... you can UPDATE an existing date in your database by adding 2 to that date using some code like this: `UPDATE othertable SET lastupdate = lastupdate + 2 WHERE id = 5423`.

Comment: Based on your comment I feel like I should add another note: If you are first updating the date within your database to the correct value... then all that needs to be done is to select that date... OR if the date you are selecting from your database is needing some sort of calculation performed on it prior to RETURNING it to (wherever/anywhere who cares where)... simply perform the necessary date calculations on that date prior to your query/application receiving that returned value/date.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this Code Novice!

Basically the SELECT needs to return two days after the date recorded on the "lastupdate" column, but without actually UPDATEing the field. This is just for our records on a monthly report that we have running, and we've decided that we'd like to see the date a hold was actually placed (which is the two day rule that places a hold on an account)